# error on check for existence in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

Question: What does "argument of type ‘bool (BST::Node::)(int)’ does not match ‘bool’
" mean?

---

Info:

I'm working on an assignment to make a binary search tree. My "contains" function doesn't compile though:

```
    bool contains(Item val)
    {
        if(val == myItem) return true;
        if(val < myItem)
            if (myLeft) return myLeft->contains;
            else return false;
        if(myRight) return myRight->contains;
        return false;

    }
```

I'm using `if(myLeft)` and `if(myRight)` to check for existence before I follow the nodes. But i get the following error message:

```
BST.h:100:38: error: argument of type ‘bool (BST<int>::Node::)(int)’ does not match ‘bool’
BST.h:102:32: error: argument of type ‘bool (BST<int>::Node::)(int)’ does not match ‘bool’
```

Where lines 100, and 102 are the ones containing if(myLeft) and if(myRight). The annoying part of this, is that my insert function works just fine:

```
    void insert(Item val)

    {
        if(val < myItem)

            if (myLeft)

                myLeft->insert(val);

            else

                myLeft = new Node(val);

        else if(val > myItem)

            if (myRight)

                myRight->insert(val);

            else

                myRight = new Node(val);
        else throw Exception("Insert()","Can't add duplicate values");

    }
```

and yet I do the exact same thing. I tried to change it to check against NULL, so it became `if(myLeft!=NULL)` and it gave the same error. Any clues as to what I'm missing here?

Comment: derp! I'm an idiot. i figured it out

Comment: Feel free to close your question if you think it is of no general value.

Comment: yea. this was a typo. so it probably isn't of much help.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to return function pointers rather than the result of calling the function.

Try this:

```
bool contains(Item val)
{
    if(val == myItem) return true;
    if(val < myItem)
        if (myLeft) return myLeft->contains(val);
        else return false;
    if(myRight) return myRight->contains(val);
    return false;

}
```

Comment: yea. I just saw that right as you posed. I am idiot feeling like.

Comment: @Narcolapser: You're not an idiot. Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes to look at your code.

Comment: indeed. or sometimes you need just need that moment of stepping away from the frustration to see what you've been missing. *sigh*

Comment: @Narcolapser: Yes, sometimes that works too.

Comment: we call them "rubber duck" problems. Stop. tape a rubber duck to your monitor. Explain to it how your program works and suddenly the problem is obvious. xD

Comment: A previous dev manager had a box of rubber ducks (all different colors) and issued one to each new hire. Works great!

Comment: I'm happy to be your "rubber duck" (even if I look like a saxophone-playing frog).

Answer (score 1):

Change `->contains` to `->contains(val)`

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo:

```
 if (myLeft) return myLeft->contains;
```

should be

```
 if (myLeft) return myLeft->contains(val);
```

The same is true for the other instance where you use `contains`.

The error is telling you that you're trying to return a function pointer when you should be returning a bool.